# ClassNotFoundException android.widget.ViewStub while launching android application in debug mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am attempting to debug an Android application with a fresh install of Android Studio 2.3 and the SDK on a new computer with fresh install of Windows 10, I receive a number of `ClassNotFoundException`s for `android.widget.ViewStub` upon starting the application. The application loads fine if I just continue through them all.

I am also able to launch the application without debugging and then attach to it without any issue.

The exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.widget.ViewStub" on path:
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.my.applicaton-2/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.my.application-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

I've cleared all settings in Android Studio and also deleted all AVDs and started fresh. I've tried disabling Instant-Run, cleaned and rebuilt the project.

I've tried this using both the API 25 x86 and API 24 x86 images with the same result.

I've seen this posted about an old version of Android Studio from 2015, with no solution at [Android Studio 1.2.2 ClassNotFoundException android.widget.viewstub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31678325/935779)

Worth noting is that this application ran fine on my previous computer under Android Studio 2.3, with no changes done since.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: This is a stretch but under the generated `.gradle` folder, do you have multiple folders for different versions of the gradle plugin?

Comment: I deleted that folder and let it regenerate, but still had the issue. I am now reinstalling all of Android Studio and the SDK to see if it will resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue, and this was due to me having a typo in the package name inside of one of the `gradle.build` files. As I looked through the debugging output, I found 1 line that was missing an `e` in the package name.

This was not caught by the compiler nor by Android Studio.

Also Android Studio does not seem to search all files even if you do `Edit > Find in Path...` and choose `Whole project`.

I ended up using Notepad++ to search my source code directory and found the typo.