# Android: Contextual Menu Compilation Error

Tags: android

When I touched the item list(s) in the ListView, it was supposed to show the Context Menu. But I didn't get one.
Here is the Code for Java:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        ListView listView;
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
            list.add("Strawberry");
            list.add("Gooseberry");
            list.add("Blueberry");
            list.add("Mulberry");
            list.add("Raspberry");
            adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>
                (this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            registerForContextMenu(listView);//pass listView to 
                 registerForContextMenu

        }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }
}
```

Here is XML code for activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ccc"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.iox_prime.menudemo.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MENU DEMO"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#999" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#999" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is XML for Menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:title="Delete"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:title="Edit"/>
</menu>
```

There was no error during the execution. But when I ran the program in Debug mode with breakpoints, it throws ClassNotFoundException. It says, it can't find android.widget.ViewStub . Please check the image attached here. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT35Q.png)

Comment: possible answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678325/android-studio-1-2-2-classnotfoundexception-android-widget-viewstub

Answer (score 0):

Found answer: As a matter of fact, this was so simple: Contextual Menu was never meant to just touch. It was meant to touch and hold. I touched and held the Menu items and it worked just as I wished!